# How to feed values in constructor in testcase in NestJs(jest)?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, testcase

I am using NestJs framework in my project. Here i want to write  testcase for a service file. But i am facing an issue in feeding the value of `this.userPool` in the service file.I am getting `userPoolId` and `clientId` undefined error.

I tried different solutions, but nothing works for me.

service.js

```
export class AuthService {
 private userPool: CognitoUserPool;
 constructor(private readonly authConfig: AuthConfig) {
   this.userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
     UserPoolId: this.authConfig.userPoolId,
     ClientId: this.authConfig.clientId,
   });
 }

authenticateUser(user: AuthCredentialsDto) {
   try {
     const { userName, password } = user;

     const authenticateDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
       Username: userName,
       Password: password,
     });
     const userData = {
       Username: userName,
       Pool: this.userPool,
     };

     const newUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       ------------------------
   --------------------------------
     });
   } catch (error) {
     throw new BadRequestException(error.message);
   }
 }
```

service.spec.ts

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import {
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
  CognitoUserAttribute,
  CognitoUserPool,
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
import { AuthConfig } from './cognito.service';

// const mockCognitoUserPool = () => ({
//   registerUser: jest.fn(),
// });

describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;
  let authConfig: AuthConfig;
  let userPool: CognitoUserPool;
  userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: authConfig.userPoolId,
    ClientId: authConfig.clientId,
  });
  // let userPool;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        AuthConfig,
        userPool
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
    authConfig = module.get<AuthConfig>(AuthConfig);
    // cognitoUserPool = module.get<CognitoUserPool>(CognitoUserPool);
  });

  describe('authenticateUser', () => {
    it('calls registerUser and returns the result', async () => {
      const mockUser = {
        userName: 'usernme',
        password: 'password',
      };

      // tasksRepository.findOne.mockResolvedValue(mockTask);
      const result = await service.authenticateUser(mockUser);
      expect(result).toEqual('result');
    });
  });

  // it('should be defined', () => {
  //   expect(service).toBeDefined();
  // });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to spell your username property ‘usernme’ in the test file?

Comment: Its a sample value i have given for mock data

Comment: Yeah I just caught that, sorry. That’s what I get for trying to answer at 11pm